# Integer not working bukkit

Tags: java, integer, bukkit

```java
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args){
  Player player = (Player) sender;
  if(commandLabel.equalsIgnoreCase("FlyTime")
     || commandLabel.equalsIgnoreCase("ft")){
    if(args.length ==0){
      player.sendMessage(
        ChatColor.DARK_BLUE + "[FlyTime] " + ChatColor.GREEN
        + player.getDisplayName() + ChatColor.DARK_RED + " " + number
        + ChatColor.GREEN + " Secconds remain until "
        + ChatColor.AQUA + "FlyTime " + ChatColor.RED + "Enjoy!");
    }
    else if(args.length ==1){
      if(player.isOp()){
        number = args[0];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is trying to make the argument change the integer's value it just doesn't want to change.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should check if CommandSender is an instance of a Player (the command could be sent from the console):

```
if (sender instanceof Player) {
```

You're getting the number from the arguments correctly, but I don't see you ever using it. Try sending the player a message with the number after `if(player.isOp()){`

Answer (score 0):

i'm guessing you have

```
private int number;
```

somewhere in your code.

```
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args){
  if(sender instanceof Player) //first add what August said; check if its a player.
  {
  Player player = (Player) sender;
  if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("FlyTime") || cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("ft")){ //second its a common method to use command name instead of command label.
    if(args.length ==0)
    {
      player.sendMessage(
        ChatColor.DARK_BLUE + "[FlyTime] " + ChatColor.GREEN
        + player.getDisplayName() + ChatColor.DARK_RED + " " + number
        + ChatColor.GREEN + " Secconds remain until "
        + ChatColor.AQUA + "FlyTime " + ChatColor.RED + "Enjoy!");
    }
    else if(args.length ==1)
     {
      if(player.isOp())
      {
        System.out.println("PRE-NUMBER:" + number); //display the number
        number = args[0];
        System.out.println("NUMBER: " + number); //do a check to see if the number has changed
      }
    }
   }
  }
}
```

if this doesn't fix it then you have messed something besides the given code up.